# tracking software for Omaha Hi/Low

Tags: software, omaha-hi-lo, pokertracker

I was looking for a software like Holdem manager that will give me the same info for Omaha Hi/low, but couldn't find one.

is there a good poker tracker or software for Omaha Hi/Low?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poker Tracker has a [version for Omaha](https://www.pokertracker.com/products/PT4/purchase.php). It also works for Omaha Hi/Lo.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy a Holdem Manager version that does do Omaha, its called Omaha Manager :)

You can find it here:

[Omaha Manager](http://www.holdemmanager.com/buy/221/omaha-manager-2)

You can even get it for free if you use one of their promotions:

[Get it Free](http://www.holdemmanager.com/store/poker-sites.php)